# What is maximum count of friends on GoogleTalk friend list?

Tags: chat, google-talk

I am developing a client for GoogleTalk server and need to know maximum count of friends Google allows a user to add to his/her friend list.

Comment: [Obviously the maximum count of friends is about 6,901,000,000 people as of this time of writing.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_population)

Comment: Back in 2010, I remember a friend hit the limit by having the “Add people I communicate with often to my Friends List.” feature enabled. Around 10000 entries the chat feature stopped working and only deleting 90% of the contacts enabled it again. I suspect such limitation would be enforced by the client-IDE though and not the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can find pretty much everything you need to know to build a GTalk client at the [GTalk developer's home](http://code.google.com/apis/talk/talk_developers_home.html) page. GTalk uses the standard [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/) protocol, with a few extensions for additional features. You shouldn't need to know such limits if they even exist. If they do exist, there is no reason they could not be raised the next day. In general, it's a bad idea to use fixed-constants for buffer sizes, array sizes, etc. There is no reason to not allow the number of contacts to vary dynamically at runtime.

If you are using C++, you can use a [vector](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html) or [list](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/List.html) for a list whose size can grow. In Java, you can use a [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of which [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and [LinkedList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)
are implementations for a dynamically-sized list. In Python, the list type grows dynamically. Pretty much every language has a notion of a dynamic array or a linked list (depending on what kind of access pattern and storage requirements you need). If you use a database of some kind, database cursors can read over arbitrary numbers of rows. Can you explain why you believe that you need to have a predefined fixed number of permitted contacts?

Comment: I don't need that limitation because of programming language restriction. I need to know because the program provides a service that informs customers of a Bank about their accounts. First I try to send IM to costumers without adding them to service "friend list" but Google talk (against Yahoo and other XMPP servers) only delivers IM to friends (probably an anti-spam policy). So Google account of this service must have thousands or millions of friends (i.e. costumers).

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a static maximum number for a list, then i strongly suggest you review your approach. What language are you using? In any modern language, the maximum number of elements in a list/array/whatever is irrelevant.They all provide datatypes for that that are only capped by your RAM memory.

Comment: I don't need that limitation because of programming language restriction.